# An image is getting cropped to 5px tall in Windows. Inspect element is showing an 'intrinsic size'

Tags: image, size, intrinsic-content-size, intrinsic-ratio

I have never heard of an intrinsic image size until today, but I have some hero images that are around 1200 x 500 pixels in size after being cropped within CraftCMS. However, when viewed on my Project Manager's Windows machine, it is showing a super super super blurry image.

When we look at it in inspect element it is a 1200 x 5 pixel image labelled with "intrinsic". See screenshot below for more.

[image: Intrinsic Image Size]

I have never encountered this before so I don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: [tag:intrinsics] is for C/C++ (or whatever language) compiler builtins like `_mm_add_ps` for x86 SIMD packed-float addition, or ARM `__clz` for the `clz` instruction to count leading zeros in an integer.  Totally different usage of a similar term.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with srcset on my PM's machine. Resolved.